# Error- cannot find C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\TextTemplating\14.0\texttransform.exe tool

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2017

I get following error even though the exe exists in specified path. I tried uninstalling clarius.Transformonbuild nuget package and reinstalling. But it still keeps giving the error. My project is in vs2017 and I copied it from another machine.

> cannot find C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\TextTemplating\14.0\texttransform.exe tool

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Anyone got any resolutions for this issue?

Comment: Please refrain from adding chatty/conversation material into questions; it will not get you an answer faster. What _will_ help is updates from your earnest and ongoing research that you are doing while waiting for responses.